# Como puedo saber el nombre de la tabla en la que se hizo el select con c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un método genérico en el cual ejecuto una consulta y obtengo dinámicamente las columnas devueltas. Claramente la finalidad es poder ejecutar cualquier consulta sin saber la estructura de la consulta como tal:

```
 public async Task<List<List<object>>> SelectFromDatabase(ConexionSQL con, string consulta)
        {


            List<List<object>> resultados = new List<List<object>>();



            try
            {
                using (var conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=" + con.Servidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + con.BD + ";User Id=" + con.Usuario + ";Password=" + con.Password + ";Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
                {

                    await conexion.OpenAsync();

                    using (var comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion))
                    {
                        var reader = await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync();


                        foreach (var item in reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>())
                        {
                            List<object> columnas = new List<object>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < item.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                if (item.GetValue(i) != null)
                                {

                                    var anonimo = new { columna = item.GetName(i), valor = item.GetValue(i) };


                                    columnas.Add(anonimo);
                                }
                            }

                            resultados.Add(columnas);
                        }

                    }
                }


                return resultados;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                List<object> columnas = new List<object>();

                var anonimo = new { columna = "error", valor = e.ToString() };

                columnas.Add(anonimo);

                resultados.Add(columnas);

                return resultados;
            }


        }
```

Esto funciona bien, sin embargo me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de obtener el dato del nombre de la tabla donde se ejecuto esa consulta luego de ejecutarla??????

Comment: El select devuelto no tiene nombre de tabla.. si lo buscaras desde el select de entrada, cual seria la tabla en el caso de un join o un sub select?

Comment: Si puede modificar el código que suminstró en su pregunta, coloque un punto de interrupción en esta línea `using (var comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion))` y verifique el valor de `consulta`.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Obtengo la consulta como un string , es decir "select * from loquesea" pero las consultas pueden tener joins, subconsultas etc y no creo que sea buena idea intentar obtener la tabla de ese string ?? Pues como sabría por ejemplo si se esta usando un esquema diferente a dbo por ejemplo?

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez ese tipo de información debe ir detallada en la pregunta. Este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959531/12511801) muestra una opción; otra opción es usar `SqlConnection.GetSchema`, pero tendría que comparar todas las tablas de la base de datos...

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes tampoco es viable usar GetSchema porque pueden haber 2 tablas con los mismos campos y mismo tipo pero con diferente nombre.

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez ayudaría entender mejor si en su pregunta suministra un ejemplo del resultado deseado. Si es un desarrollo, toca seguir mirando opciones; pero, si es por depuración de qué consulta(s) se ejecutan, puede usar SQL Profiler.